# Ordering First Model in Association with Second Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, many-to-many

I'm working on my first project with RoR and I need to create many to many relationship between two models but with possibility of ordering objects of first model in association to second model.

Let's say that I have two following models
- Customer
- Route

I want assign many Customers to many Routes but with storing order of this association, so for example

```
-Route 1
--Customer 2, position 1
--Customer 1, position 2

-Route 2
--Customer 3, position 1
--Customer 1, position 2
```

I think I have to use for it has_many :through and belong_to and creat "position" field in in-middle-table but then how to make this field accessible and editable?

Answer (score 3):

You could go with `:through`:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :routes, :through => bookings
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :routes, through => :bookings
end
```

Your Bookings model would keep the date/position and you could access them with:

```
c = Customer.first
c.routes(:include => :bookings, :order => "bookings.position")
```

Comment: How would you operate then on this position field? Would it be assigned to customer as well?

Comment: For a given booking:

c = Customer.first
b = c.bookings.first
b.position

But the code above already returns the routes in order, you could just pass it to a partial (or loop over the result set in a controller).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :routes, :through => :trips
  ...
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :route
  // has a ordinal called 'seq'
  ...
end

class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, :through => :trips
  ...
end
```

You should be able to access the ordinal field via @customer.routes[0].seq
I haven't tested it and my rails skills are long dull but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

cite's solution is right. to access the middle table, try:

```
c.bookings # this will return the 'middle table' which then you have the access to the positions 
c.bookings.first.position
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to display all customers assignes to one routes, so the query sent to database are:

SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `bookings` ON `customers`.id = `bookings`.customer_id WHERE ((`bookings`.route_id = 1))

and then

SELECT `bookings`.* FROM `bookings` WHERE (`bookings`.customer_id IN (1,2,3))

..so, the 2nd query does not contain enought information in WHERE calus, because it's selecting information for all routes for specific customers, not just about specific customers for specific route (id=1).

..is RoR doing some extra filtering after fetching this data?

btw. I have :include => :bookings added into Route model

Comment: but the first query works right? the second query the extra query to pre-load all the bookings, because you have 'inlcude' in your Route model. 'Include' tells the rails to load all the bookings related to the first query, in case you need it in the future.

Comment: yes, but then there is no association between specific customer and specific record in bookings, related to that user and that route, so I'm not able to get position